# R-caret - how to persist model

Tags: r, r-caret

I am using R with `caret` package to create a predictive model. I am rather satisfied with my model and would like to persist it to run it on daily basis.

Unfortunately, I am very new to R and don't know how to do it.

Could you please help me? Thanks!

Here's the code I use:

```
library(caret)
library(e1071)
library(data.table)
library(pracma)

mydata<-read.csv("C:/test1.txt", header=T , sep="\t")
setDT(mydata)

mydata[,mmc:=movavg(mydata$a2,2)]
mydata[,mml:=movavg(mydata$a2,5)]

mydata[, y:=shift(a2, 4, type="lead", fill=mydata$a2[length(mydata$a2)])]

training<-mydata[296:4198,]
testing<-mydata[4199:length(mydata$a2),]

logit.fit<-train(y ~., data=training, type="brnn")
pred<-predict(logit.fit, newdata=testing)

testing[,pred:=pred]
write.csv(testing, "C:/result_machine_learning.csv")
```

INPUT file format (C:/test1.txt)

```
a1  b1  b2  a2  c

7277.68 7291.54 7221.00 7240.70 0

7266.55 7276.45 7197.38 7223.64 0
```

Answer (score 1):

**1.** One way you can persist your model is by using saveRDS and readRDS:

```
logit.fit <- train(y ~., data=training, type="brnn")
saveRDS(logit.fit, "model.rds")
```

and after you run it, you can substitute the training and saving with reading from the file:

```
logit.fit <- readRDS("model.rds")
pred <- predict(logit.fit, newdata=testing)
```

**2.** Alternatively, though, less preferably, you can use `save` and `load` functions:

```
logit.fit <- train(y ~., data=training, type="brnn")
save(logit.fit, file="model.Rdata")
```

and then load it like this:

```
load("model.RData")
pred <- predict(logit.fit, newdata=testing)
```

**UPDATE:**
From the [documentation](http://topepo.github.io/caret/model-training-and-tuning.html#extracting-predictions-and-class-probabilities) of caret:

> objects produced by the train function contain the “optimized” model in the finalModel sub-object.

Therefore, you're able to pull out your trained model like this:
`logit.fit$finalModel`
Also, there's a nifty `summary(model)` function which you may also find useful, just run `summary(logit.fit)` after you train your model.

Comment: Thanks Orif, this doesn't answer my question fully but will help me in the future.

Maybe I was not clear, sorry. In fact, how can I know the coefficients/the equation used, so I can use it myself outside of R for new values of the columns a1, b1, b2, a2 and c?

Comment: @Hervé, I've updated the answer, hopefully you'll find it useful.

Comment: Thanks Orif, this is useful information as well, but it still doesn't answer my question.
The model predicts column "y" out of columns a1  b1  b2  a2  c. So there must be somewhere the equation it uses to predict this column "y"; maybe something like y = c1*a1 + c2*b1 + c3*b2 + c4*c1 + c5*c

Comment: The equation you're looking for exists only in concept, the implementation uses linear algebra under the hood and operates in batches of data. You'll have to derive the equation manually, and I'm not exactly sure how. Here's the closest thing I've found that you can try to implement once you figure out all the input required. https://www.researchgate.net/post/Is_it_possible_to_obtain_an_equation_between_neural_network_input_and_output_value_How_can_I_do_it

Comment: But since you don't build the NN yourself but rely on an implementation, I'm not sure about its specific architecture. I've also found presumably its source code: https://github.com/topepo/caret/blob/master/models/files/brnn.R which may help you figure it out.

Comment: I understand ... thanks Orif for the links!
This will help me for sure ...